# Beautiful Soup returns an empty string when website has text

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Considering this website here: https://dlnr.hawaii.gov/dsp/parks/oahu/ahupuaa-o-kahana-state-park/

I'm looking to scrape the content under the headings on the right. Here is my sample code which should return the list of contents but is returning empty strings:

```
import requests as req
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = req.get('https://dlnr.hawaii.gov/dsp/parks/oahu/ahupuaa-o-kahana-state-park/').text
soup = bs(r)

par = soup.find('h3', text= 'Facilities')

for sib in par.next_siblings:
    print(sib)
```

This returns:

```
<ul class="park_icon">
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</ul>
```

The website doesn't show any div element with that class. Also, the list items are not being captured.

Answer (score 7):

Facilities, and other info in that frame, are loaded dynamically by `JavaScript`, so `bs4` doesn't see them in the source `HTML` because they're simply not there.

However, you can query the endpoint and get all the info you need.

Here's how:

```python
import json
import re
import time

import requests

headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) "
                  "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) "
                  "Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36",
    "referer": "https://dlnr.hawaii.gov/",
}

endpoint = f"https://stateparksadmin.ehawaii.gov/camping/park-site.json?parkId=57853&_={int(time.time())}"
response = requests.get(endpoint, headers=headers).text
data = json.loads(re.search(r"callback\((.*)\);", response).group(1))
print("\n".join(f for f in data["park info"]["facilities"]))
```

Output:

```
Boat Ramp
Campsites
Picnic table
Restroom
Showers
Trash Cans
Water Fountain
```

Here's the entire `JSON`:

```
{
  "park info": {
    "name": "Ahupua\u02bba \u02bbO Kahana State Park",
    "id": 57853,
    "island": "Oahu",
    "activities": [
      "Beachgoing",
      "Camping",
      "Dogs on Leash",
      "Fishing",
      "Hiking",
      "Hunting",
      "Sightseeing"
    ],
    "facilities": [
      "Boat Ramp",
      "Campsites",
      "Picnic table",
      "Restroom",
      "Showers",
      "Trash Cans",
      "Water Fountain"
    ],
    "prohibited": [
      "No Motorized Vehicles/ATV's",
      "No Alcoholic Beverages",
      "No Open Fires",
      "No Smoking",
      "No Commercial Activities"
    ],
    "hazards": [],
    "photos": [],
    "location": {
      "latitude": 21.556086,
      "longitude": -157.875579
    },
    "hiking": [
      {
        "name": "Nakoa Trail",
        "id": 17,
        "activities": [
          "Dogs on Leash",
          "Hiking",
          "Hunting",
          "Sightseeing"
        ],
        "facilities": [
          "No Drinking Water"
        ],
        "prohibited": [
          "No Bicycles",
          "No Open Fires",
          "No Littering/Dumping",
          "No Camping",
          "No Smoking"
        ],
        "hazards": [
          "Flash Flood"
        ],
        "photos": [],
        "location": {
          "latitude": 21.551087,
          "longitude": -157.881228
        },
        "has_google_street": false
      },
      {
        "name": "Kapa\u2018ele\u2018ele Trail",
        "id": 18,
        "activities": [
          "Dogs on Leash",
          "Hiking",
          "Sightseeing"
        ],
        "facilities": [
          "No Drinking Water",
          "Restroom",
          "Trash Cans"
        ],
        "prohibited": [
          "No Bicycles",
          "No Open Fires",
          "No Littering/Dumping",
          "No Camping",
          "No Smoking"
        ],
        "hazards": [],
        "photos": [],
        "location": {
          "latitude": 21.554744,
          "longitude": -157.876601
        },
        "has_google_street": false
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm doing this with Scrapy and crawling through multiple pages. Any idea how to do this with Scrapy?

Comment: Nope, I don't use scrapy, sorry.

Comment: Your initial attempt in the post above doesn't indicate anything about scrapy. You should not come up with any new requirement once your question is answered. However, you can always create a new post describing any new issue @maverick.

Answer (score 2):

You've already been given the necessary answer and I thought I would provide insight into another way you could have divined what was going on (other than looking in network traffic).

Let's start with your observation:

> the list items are not being captured.

Examining each of the li elements we see that the html is of the form
`class="parkicon facilities icon01"` - where 01 is a variable number representing the particular icon visible on the page.

A quick search through the associated source files will show you that these numbers, and their corresponding facility reference are listed in
`https://dlnr.hawaii.gov/dsp/wp-content/themes/hic_state_template_StateParks/js/icon.js`:

`var w_fac_icons={"ADA Accessible":"01","Boat Ramp":"02","Campsites":"03","Food Concession":"04","Lodging":"05","No Drinking Water":"06","Picnic Pavilion":"07","Picnic table":"08","Pier Fishing":"09","Restroom":"10","Showers":"11","Trash Cans":"12","Walking Path":"13","Water Fountain":"14","Gift Shop":"15","Scenic Viewpoint":"16"}`

If you then search the source html for `w_fac_icons` you will come across (lines 560-582):

```
// Icon Facilities
        var i_facilities =[];
        for(var i=0, l=parkfac.length; i < l ; ++i) {
            var icon_fac = '<li class="parkicon facilities icon' + w_fac_icons[parkfac[i]] + '"><span>' + parkfac[i] + '</span></li>';
            i_facilities.push(icon_fac);
        };
        if (l > 0){
            jQuery('#i_facilities ul').html(i_facilities.join(''));
        } else {
            jQuery('#i_facilities').hide();
        }
```

This shows you how the li element html is constructed through javascript running on the page with `parkfac[i]` returning the text description in the `span`, and `w_fac_icons[parkfac[i]]` returning the numeric value associated with the icon in the class value.

If you track back `parkfac` you will arrive at line 472

```
var parkfac = parkinfo.facilities;
```

If you then track back function `parkinfo` you will arrive at line 446 onwards, where you will find the ajax request which dynamically grabs the json data used to update the webpage:

```
function parkinfo() {
    var campID = 57853;

    jQuery.ajax( {
        type:'GET',
        url: 'https://stateparksadmin.ehawaii.gov/camping/park-site.json',
        data:"parkId=" + campID,
```

`data` can be passed within a querystring as params using a GET.

This is therefore the request you are looking for in the network tab.

Comment: That's pretty much how I figured it out. Nicely done! +1

Answer (score -1):

While the above answers technically answer the question, if you're scraping data from multiple pages its not feasible to look into endpoints each time.

The simpler approach when you know you're handling a javascript page is to simply load it with `scrapy-splash` or `selenium`. Then the javascript elements can be parsed with `BeautifulSoup`.